# What does "desert island band" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, definition

What does "desert island band" mean? I've seen a lot of mentions of this term, but I've never found exact definition. They call a lot of bands that term. Black Sabbath, Misfits, Dare to Defy.

Comment: [Could be related to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_Island_Discs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This probably has to do with the idea of a [*deserted island*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_island).

> A **desert island**, **deserted island** or **uninhabited island** is an island that is not populated by humans. Uninhabited islands are often used in movies or stories about shipwrecked people, and are also used as stereotypes for the idea of "paradise".

This "desert island" is popular in hypothetical games where it is asked

> If you were on a deserted island and you could on do/bring *X* number of things, what would you do/bring?

So in this instance, one example would be

> If you were stuck on a deserted island, and you could only listen to **one** band for the rest of your life, which band would it be?

As you can image, many people would choose famous, successful bands like Black Sabbath and Misfits. So, you might call them "desert island" bands.

"Desert island" is not limited to bands. There are desert island [books](http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/anne-theriault-/desert-island-books_b_3332871.html) and even desert island [celebrities](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/3exwep/youre_stuck_on_a_desert_island_with_5_celebrities/).

---

Here is [an example](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskWomen/comments/1rumt4/ladies_lets_play_that_desert_island_game_youre/) I found on Reddit:

> Ever played the game "desert island"? Premise being that you're stuck on a desert island for an indefinite amount of time, and you can only bring a handful of items. I'm curious to know what you'd bring.
>   Categories (answer all or some):
>
> - You can bring 3 **books**.
> - You can bring 3 **movies**.
> - You can bring 3 **food items**.
> - You can bring an ipod with **1 genre of music** on it.
> - You can bring 3 **personal items** (such as photos, things that are meaningful to you)
> - You can bring 3 **survival items** (such as matches, etc)
> - You can bring 1 **person to keep you company** (can be a celebrity, someone dead or alive, someone you know,

Comment: There's a British radio show based on this concept: Desert Island Discs.  A celebrity chooses eight records, a book and a luxury item that they would take to a desert island.